# Non-Convex Optimization and Lagrangian Optimization

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, lagrange-multiplier

Let $f,g: \mathcal{X} \to \mathbb{R}$. Let $f$ and $g$ be concave. We want to solve the following opitmization problem
\begin{align}
\max_{x \in \mathcal{X}} f(x) \\
\text{ s.t. } g(x) \le c
\end{align} 
where $c\ge 0$.

**My question:** Since $g(x)$ is not convex the above problem does not fall into the category of convex optimization.

Keeping the above in mind, would the Lagrangian approach still given a neccesary codition on the  optimality?

That is if we define 
\begin{align}
L(x)=f(x)-\lambda (c-g(x))
\end{align}

then the optimall solution must be a stationary point of $L(x)$?

Comment: Generally you need some regularity conditions, so it is not true in general. Take any $f(x) = x$ and $g(x) = c+x^2$, then the solution is $x=0$ but clearly $L(0,\lambda) \neq 0$ for any $\lambda$.

Answer (score 1):

Take $f(x) = x$, $c=0$ and $g(x) = \min(0,x^3)$. Note that $f,g$ are concave.

The solution is $x=0$, but $g'(0) = 0$, hence for any $\lambda$ we have
${\partial L(0,\lambda) \over \partial x} = 1$.

**Note**:

${\partial L(x,\lambda) \over \partial x} = {\partial f(x) \over \partial x} + \lambda {\partial g(x) \over \partial x}$, and so we have
${\partial L(0,\lambda) \over \partial x} = 1$.

Comment: $\max\{0,x^3\}$ is concave? Seems convex to me.

Comment: @MichaelGrant: Thanks, I meant $\min$.

Comment: Why is  $L(0,\lambda)=1$ it becaue you took $c=1$?

Comment: @Boby: I'm sorry, I had a typo. above. The $L(0,\lambda)$ should have been the partial with respect to $x$. I have fixed it.