# When is the solution to Lagrangian equal to the solution of the constrained optimization problem?

Tags: optimization, nonlinear-optimization, lagrange-multiplier

I am trying to understand when the solution found by Lagrangian is equal to the original optimization problem with equality constraints. [This post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/94375/is-a-constrained-optimization-problem-equalivant-to-its-lagrangian-form) is related to my question but that question is about inequality constraints and the answer states "under a broad range of conditions" the two are equal. [Other questions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2066489/non-convex-optimization-and-lagrangian-optimization) seem to discuss special cases such as optimization of convex functions.

Specifically, consider the following optimization problem:
\begin{align}
x^\star = \arg \max_{x \in \mathcal{X}} f(x)\\
\text{s.t. } g(x) = 0
\end{align}

- Variable $x$ is a vector.
- $x^\star$ is a unique solution and there exists $x^\star \in \mathcal{X}$ such that $g(x^\star) = 0$.
- Functions $f(x), g(x)$ are differentiable with respect to $x$ but they are **not** convex/concave and we don't have $g(x) \geq 0$.
- The set $\mathcal{X}$ might not be a continuous set and may just be a finite set so we generally can't use arguments that introduce gradients of $f(x)$ and $g(x).

My understanding is that the Lagrange method forms the following optimization problem:
\begin{align}
\tilde x, \tilde \lambda = \arg \max_{x \in \mathcal{X}} \arg \min_\lambda f(x) - \lambda g(x).
\end{align}

**My questions:**

1. When is $\tilde x = x^\star$, given that we assumed $x^\star$ is unique and $\tilde x$ is the actual optimum of the Lagrange form not just $\nabla f(\tilde x) = 0$?
2. I am confused about what $\tilde \lambda$ should be. My understanding is if we define $\tilde \lambda(x) = \arg \min_\lambda -\lambda g(x)$, then the solution is

\begin{align}
\tilde{\lambda}(x) = \begin{cases}
- \infty \quad & \text{if } g(x) > 0\\
+ \infty \quad & \text{if } g(x) < 0\\
\text{any number} \quad & \text{if } g(x) = 0
\end{cases}
\end{align}

If $\tilde{x} = x^\star$, since we know $g(x^\star) = 0$, does that mean $\tilde \lambda$ can be anything?

3. If No. 2 is true, what happens if we find $\tilde \lambda$ by $\min_{\lambda \in [-B, B]}$ over a bounded interval?
4. In some examples, I have seen a discussion of on strong duality and whether $\max_x \min_\lambda f(x) - \lambda g(x) = \min_\lambda \max_x  f(x) - \lambda g(x)$. Does strong duality have anything to do with $\tilde x$ being equal to $x^\star$?